# SQL query with linq in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm having problems coming up with the correct query to get the data out of my ERD. So in the image below is a simplified version for clarity.

So a user can join a group this relation is kept in the UserPerGroup table, a group can have events. now I want to be able to get all events (descriptions/ objects) for every group the user is part of. I'm using Linq in a MVC .NET project but don't mind if I get a raw (MS) SQL query.

Thanks

[Simplified ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsCQ7.jpg)

EDIT: can the query below be converted to the following Linq format?

```
return db.Event. ... .ToList();
```

wich would return an IEnumbarable?

```
select e.id,e.[description]  from [User] u 
Inner join UserPerGroup upg on upg.userid=u.id 
Inner join [event] e on e.groupid=upg.groupid
Where u.id=[USER_ID_VALUE]
```

query from Rohit Padma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple LINQ [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) operator to correlate the entities like this (I'm guessing the names):

```
int userId = ...;

var query =
    from e in db.Event
    join ug in db.UsersPerGroup on e.GroupId equals ug.GroupId
    where ug.UserId == userId
    select e;

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this, I only saw the basic around Linq. This will help me a lot to solve future problems!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this raw SQL query helps.

```
select e.id,e.[description]  from [User] u 
Inner join UserPerGroup upg on upg.userid=u.id 
Inner join [event] e on e.groupid=upg.groupid
Where u.id=[USER_ID_VALUE]
```

Comment: would wanne give you +1 for the query but my reputation is to low. But thanks again!

Comment: Its okay :)  hope it helped.